# Line break in VBA ComboBox item

Tags: vba

How can I add a line break to an item in a ComboBox in VBA?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  ComboBox1.List = Array("Test1","Test2", "Test3" & Chr(13) & "more text")
End Sub
```

Adding `Chr(13)` above actually adds a paragraph symbol instead of a line break.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this? If you give more details, someone may be able to offer an alternative solution.

Comment: I have a long line of text I need to display. I want to break it for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: How about displaying `Long line of text ...` in the combo, and when it is selected, populate a textbox with the full line?

Comment: I was hoping to not have to change the UI to handle this. If there are no other solutions then maybe this is the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [variable size items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#owner_drawn).

The MSForms combobox, being a windowless (lightweight) control, does not support this.